# Geocoding service

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I'm looking for geocoding service, which can provide 1 million queries per day.

I've already read about google/yahoo api, but unfortunately none of them can offer this quantity.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you geocoding by address or by IP?

Comment: Thanks for replies. @Matt, I'm interesting in geocoding by address. We have a large dataset with 16million addresses where we need to obtain lat/lon for all records. It requires a fairly high volume due to short deadline.

Comment: Ok. See my answer below then, as it applies well to your situation. Using the API, you could probably get it done in a few hours if you filled each request with 100 addresses. Or, you could upload your list to our list processor which will flag duplicates across the entire set and CASS-certify your list at the same time, while geocoding.

Comment: @user869752 After talking to you on the phone, I failed to ask where the data came from originally.  Where did you obtain your lat/lon data and how do you know that it is inaccurate.  Usually "accuracy" is not as big an issue as "precision".  A lat/lon coordinate can be 5 miles from your location and still be accurate if the precision level is a 6 mile radius.  However, if you need more "precision" you will need a better system.  There are many lat/lon lists that relate to individual ZIP codes.  These are available for under $100 but the precision is only the ZIP code level.  More info please?

Answer (score 2):

Google, Yahoo, MapQuest (licensed service) or Microsoft will be more than happy to allow you to use their API with this kind of volume, with their premium plans.

If you want this for free, [MapQuest Open](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) runs Nominatim, a free geocoder, based on OpenStreetMap data. This service is not, as of today, rate-limited.

Or, if you want more control, why not set up your own geocoder, based on [Nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

I work at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we specialize in address verification and geocoding. While I'm not sure yet (see my comment to your question) if you are geocoding by address or by IP, I know of some venues you could investigate. I'll start with some general principles then offer a recommendation or two.

There *are* services that will perform either batch geocoding or geocoding *en masse* for such large quantities. Ultimately, to service upwards of a million requests daily from a single user, the API you determine to use should have the following characteristics:

- Geo-distributed. Latency can easily double the time of a request, and over a million queries in just one day (about 11 queries/sec) can seriously affect your app's performance.
- Scalable. If one machine becomes overwhelmed servicing API requests, how will the system cope and service others pending?
- SLA with guaranteed uptime. Especially for mission-critical operations, geocoding must not get in your way, and for such a large quantity you want to make sure the availability isn't affected arbitrarily.
- Portable/lightweight. In other words, you want something that can output results in a universal format. XML is nice, but often difficult to use and has its limitations. I've personally found [JSON](http://json.org) to be a great format for sending and receiving data.
- Affordable. The premium plans of Google and Yahoo's APIs are generally designed for corporate entities, which carry a hefty cost. Your means may not allow that.

Also keep in mind that Google, OpenStreetMap (Nominatim), Yahoo, and others, don't actually verify the locations they geocode. In other words, you can give Google or OSM an address that doesn't really exist, and it will still give you coordinates --- because they perform address *approximation*, not address *verification*. Their purpose is to help you search/find things, but if you need accurate coordinates, you best make sure the address is correct.

Start looking around for APIs like this. I would suggest you start with [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api), and see how it meets your needs. We service millions of requests per day and can easily handle thousands of requests per second, and the data we return to you will only actually exist: no guessing about the addresses. It comes with an SLA, is serviced from 3 data centers across the US, and has a simple JSON output. Response times are generally around 100ms or less (excluding external latencies out of our control).

And by the way, it's free to use for 250 addresses, or queries, per month, which in your case should help you get started real easy...

If you have any further questions, I'll be happy to help you personally.

Answer (score 0):

For free? If so, you won't find such a service from a commercial company like Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, MapQuest etc. The only way is to pay for more daily queries or to use OpenStreetMap.org (OSM). However, OSM's API does only offer 2,5k queries a day, but you can download the whole map stuff (or even some parts, e.g. particular cities or countries) and put it on your own server. Note, OSM does not offer satelite or street viewing.